# how to convert a button into save button by clicking that button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a text box with value in readonly and a button if i click that button the text box has to change into editable and the button into save... using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KTYWT/

HTML

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="button" id="textbutton" value="Edit" />
```

jQuery

```
$('#textbutton').click(function(e) {
    var text = $('#textbox');

    if (text.is('[readonly]')) {
        text.removeAttr('readonly');
        $(this).val('Save');
    } else {
        text.attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $(this).val('Edit');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this using `removeAttr`  function.

For `readonly` add property `readonly="readonly"` to text and remove it on script too.

```
<script>
function func1(button)
{
    $(button).val('Save');
    $('input[type=text]').removeAttr('disabled')
}
</script>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="func1(this)" value="enable"/>
```

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zMU8E/1/)

Comment: If the user tries to post this form using Ajax, the form's values for this field will not be posted. Needs to be readonly.

Answer (score -1):

An example using jquery here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/azGPf/

```
<input id='thebox' type='text' readonly="readonly" value='locked'>
<button id='thebutton'>The Button</button>

$('#thebutton').click(function(){
    $('#thebox').removeAttr('readonly');
    $(this).html('save');
})
```

Renames the button and makes the text editable.

**EDIT** Answer edited to show 'readonly' as Eli points out

Comment: I think the question was rather focused on changing the attribute of the text that what attribute. +1 to cancel downvote